# code igniter . i have issue to show upcoming birthday of month(like July) custom

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am beginner in development i have  issue to show upcoming birthday of month(like July) guide me to please fix this problem here is code. here is code to show upcoming birthday.

```
<h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo 'Upcomming Birthday' ?> - <?php echo date("F"); ?></h3>
    <ul class="leave_apps">
        <?php
        $m = date("m"); // Month value
        $y = date("Y"); // Year value
        $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_gregorian , $m, $y);
        ?>
            <?php
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($employee); $i++) :

                $mem_bod_explode = explode("-", $employee[$i]->date_of_birth);

                $m_bday = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mem_bod_explode[1], $mem_bod_explode[2], $y);

                $start_date = date('Y-m', $m_bday) . '-01';
                $end_date = date('Y-m', $m_bday) . '-' . $num;

                if (date('Y-m-d') == date('Y-m-d', $m_bday)) {
                    $present_bday[] = $employee[$i];
                    $date = date('Y-m-d', $m_bday);
                    $pdate[] = date('d M Y', strtotime($date));

                } else if (date('Y-m-d', $m_bday) > $start_date && date('Y-m-d', $m_bday) <= $end_date) {
                    $future_bday[] = $employee[$i];
                    $date = date('Y-m-d', $m_bday);
                    $fdate[] = date('d M Y', strtotime($date));
                }

                ?>
        <?php endfor; ?>
        <?php if (!empty($present_bday)):foreach ($present_bday as $key => $v_bday): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/employee/view_employee/<?php echo $v_bday->employee_id ?>">
                    <h5>
                    <div class="pull-left">
                            <img class="img-circle"  src="<?php echo base_url() . $v_bday->photo ?>">
                    </div>
                    <span><?php echo $v_bday->first_name . ' ' . $v_bday->last_name ?></span>
                    <small class="apps_category" style="color:red">(Today)</small>
                    <p class="leave_para"><?php echo $pdate[$key]; ?></p>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you can easily do this using sql query itself. mention from and to date of next month in your model query.. If you still trying to solve ping back ill explain more on that

Comment: can you write code for this please . am beginner in development

Comment: I don't think most of the people here would write the code on your behalf.. instead we're fixing what's wrong in your code. And in this case, you need to have layers to do that.. What you've done should have been done in Codeigniter Model (CI Model is layer). Your view will only manage the layout on how you want to display the birthdate data of your employee.. can you share your db table, and controller's file?

Comment: controller fun                                                                                          { $this->admin_model->_table_name = "tbl_employee"; //table name
                                                                                                                $this->admin_model->_order_by = "employee_id"; // order by                                  
        $data['employee'] = $this->admin_model->get_by(array('status' => 1)); }

Comment: @JMS786  in db table name is employee that have date_of_birth file